# Basic question: How to send data from forms properly on HTML to Flask. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

Python code:

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template("test1.html")



@app.route('/pass', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def takename():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fname = request.form.get('firstname')
        lname = request.form.get('lastname')
        print(fname)
        print("test")
        print(lname)
        return render_template('pass.html', f=fname, l=lname)
    else:
        return("Did not work")
```

Form:

```
<form action="/pass" method=”POST”>
    <label> First Name</label>
    <input type=”text” name=”firstname”>
    <label> Last Name </label>
    <input type=”text” name=”lastname”>
    <input type="submit">

</form>
```

Pass.html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> "{{f}} </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I always end up with "Did not work" the goal is for the user to enter their first and last name, and then be redirected to the the pass.html page with the first and last name as variables. What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Logically, `request.method` must not be `'POST'` (you could print it to check its value).  Is the form submitted directly by clicking on the submit button or is thee javascript involved?

Comment: The form is submitted through the submit button (I think). If I do    ` if request.method == 'GET':` then it loads pass.html but with just "None Also it prints None, Test, None

Comment: Hmm - can you try changing `<form action="/pass" method=”POST”>` to `<form action="/pass" method="POST">`, that is using straight double-quotes around `POST` in the html?  Maybe the fancy quotes are confusing the browser.

Comment: I tried but nothing changed unfortunately :/